# C Sockets - Listened from a port, now how to send back to it?

Tags: c, sockets

I am making a web proxy using sockets in C.  Basically, I listen to a given port number, take in an HTML request from it, make the request, and then send what I get back where it came from.

I've got the first part working.  I'm able to read in the request and send it to the necessary web server, and I get a valid response.  I'm just not sure how to send that response to the port where it was asked for.

(I'm testing my code using Netcat to make the request and get a response back, and at the moment the response I am trying to send is not being printed by Netcat.)

Here's my relevant code:

```
struct sockaddr_in port;
bzero((char *) &port, sizeof(port));
port.sin_family = AF_INET;
port.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
port.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
int socket;
int acceptSocket;
char response[RESPONSE_SIZE];

socket = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
Bind(socket, (struct sockaddr *) &port, sizeof(port));
Listen(socket, 0);
acceptSocket = Accept(socket, NULL, NULL);

if (acceptSocket >= 0)
  printf("Connection open on port %s\n", argv[1]);

if (!ForwardHTTPRequest(acceptSocket, response))
      printf("Forward error\n");

shutdown(socket, 0);
Connect(socket, (struct sockaddr *) &port, sizeof(port));
Send(socket, response, strlen(response), 0);
```

The last three lines are my attempt to send the response back.  I shut down the read side of the socket, connect in order to send, and then send.  This isn't producing any response though.

Comment: Please note: The `bzero()` function is ancient, deprecated, and in the current version of POSIX.1, not even included. Use `memset()` instead. (And if your code has `bcopy()` in it, use `memcpy()` or `memmove()` instead...) Also, your code example uses functions named `Socket()`, `Bind()`, `Listen()`, `Connect()`, and `Accept()`. Are these typos, or did you actually implement functions with those names? (Case makes a difference, you see.)

Comment: calling the socket you get back from accept acceptSocket is misleading.  You should call it clientSocket or something like that to show that it corresponds to a client of yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acceptSocket` is the socket you're using for communications one the session is established. Just send a message back on that socket before you shut it down.

It's unusual to shut down the *controlling* socket unless you're absolutely sure you don't want to serve any more requests. The basic workflow of a server is:

```
create listensocket
bind listensocket
while working:
    worksocket = accept listensocket
    read and write to worksocket as much as you want
    close worksocket
shutdown/close listensocket
```

(although, for responsiveness, the actual work done on `worksocket` is farmed off to a different thread or process, so that the server can handle subsequent requests without waiting).

Comment: I love it when my problems are simple ones.  Thank you!

Comment: or in his case, just make it non-blocking, and everything should be fine.  I wouldn't involve threads at all.